# Determine whether a class has a function

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, member-functions

Using a trick (described by [Olivier Langlois](http://blog.olivierlanglois.net/index.php/2007/09/01/what_is_the_c_sfinae_principle)), I can determine whether a class has a type defined:

```
template<typename T> struct hasType
{
    template<typename C> static char test( typename C::Type );
    template<typename C> static char* test(...);
    enum{ Value= sizeof(test<T>(0))==1 };
};
```

I can also determine whether a class has a variable:

```
template<typename T> struct hasType
{
    template<typename C> static char test( decltype(C::var) );
    template<typename C> static char* test(...);
    enum{ Value= sizeof(test<T>(0))==1 };
};
```

However, neither `decltype(c::func)` nur `decltype(c::func())` (which depends on the parameters) works for member functions.
Is there a way to do this or will I have to create a functor in every class and detect it with `typename C::functor`?

**Edit**: You're both right, but since I'll also have to test for a type I'll use `decltype(&C::func)` (which should obviously be a pointer).

Comment: Good question, but it does seem to be an exact dupe, as ilya.devyatovsky points out below.